# Access Scylla on EKS with Python Driver

Tags: python, kubernetes, cassandra, amazon-eks, scylla

I am a newbie to Kubernetes. Recently, I am asked to set up Scylla on AWS. I followed the tutorial to deploy Scylla on EKS (http://operator.docs.scylladb.com/master/eks.html). Everything went well.

Then, I followed *Accessing the Database* section in another related tutorial (http://operator.docs.scylladb.com/master/generic.html).

I was able to run the commands for the first two steps:

```sh
kubectl exec -n scylla -it scylla-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-0 -- cqlsh
> DESCRIBE KEYSPACES;
```

```sh
kubectl -n scylla describe service scylla-cluster-client
```

However, I don't know how to perform the last step, which said:

> Pods running inside the Kubernetes cluster can use this Service to connect to Scylla. Here’s an example using the Python Driver:
>
> ```py
> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
> cluster = Cluster(['scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc'])
> session = cluster.connect()
> ```

The script fails to resolve `scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc`.
Therefore, I also tried different IPs, but `cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable` error is encountered.

In addition, I found that `pip` is not installed after connecting to the cluster via

```sh
kubectl exec -n scylla -it scylla-cluster-us-east-1-us-east-1a-0 -- /bin/bash
```

Can anyone help me solve the connection issue using Python driver?

It would be great if you can tell me:

1. Why scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc does not work for me?
2. What is the different between `kubectl exec -n ...`  and Cassandra drivers?
3. Which IPs should I use? I noticed that there are cluster IPs from Kubernetes, internal IPs from Kubernetes, and public IPs of the EC2 machines from AWS. If public IP is needed, do I need to open the ports (e.g. 9042) on AWS? How to make it more secure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc` is a k8s resolvable DNS address, so only works from pods hosted on the same cluster (and namespace). You can't use it from the outside
2. `kubectl` exec runs a command on one of the Scylla pods, so essentially you are running the command on the Scylla node itself and connecting to `localhost` on that node. In contrast, `scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc` is connecting remotely (but within the k8s network)
3. You don't need to use an IP - use the `scylla-cluster-client.scylla.svc` DNS name. If you want to use IP addresses you can manually resolve the DNS name or read the IP addresses of the Scylla pods using the k8s API - but there's really no reason to do that.
   If you want to connect from outside the cluster you would need a public service or something like that - basically a k8s managed proxy. In theory you could allow the public pods but that's highly inadvisable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually want to connect from outside the cluster, could you elaborate more on how to set up a "k8s managed proxy" in your answer? I tried to changed the service type of `scylla-cluster-client` to `LoadBalance`, but it is not allowed.

Comment: If you are trying to connect from a dev machine, an easy and secure way would be [telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/)